# QModelIndex::data not working

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtreeview, qtgui

I have a QTreeView in my application with a data model. I'm capturing when items are double clicked with the following slot:

```
void MainWindow::on_treeView_doubleClicked(const QModelIndex &index)
{
    if (index.parent().isValid()) {
        QSharedPointer<GMResource> resource;

       resource = index.data(Qt::UserRole).value<QSharedPointer<GMResource> >();
        Workspace::GetSingleton()->OpenResourceEditor(resource);
    }
}
```

I expected the `QModelIndex::data()` method to (execute and) return the underlying `QStandardItem::data()` for the item referenced by that index, however its not returning anything. I set a breakpoint in my `QStandardItem::data()` method, and it's not even being called, so I might have incorrectly assumed what `QModelIndex::data()` actually returns.

How can I access the item data referenced by the `QModelIndex` (eg. Access to the original `QStandardItem` I added to the model).

Here is my `data()` method for my `QStandardItem` derived class:

```
virtual QVariant data( int role) const {
     if (role==Qt::UserRole) {
            return QVariant(resource);
     }
        return QStandardItem::data(role);
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to the problem.

I replaced this code:

```
return QVariant(resource);
```

With this code:

```
 QVariant r;
 r.setValue<QSharedPointer<GMResource> >(resource);
 return r;
```

Seems to be working as expected. I guess the data() method was being executed, but the breakpoints weren't being triggered for some reason.

Comment: Not sure but I guess that the tree lines are equivalent to `QVariant::fromValue(resource);`. The problem why this isn't equivalent to `QVariant(resource)` is that there is no templated constructor, so it will be cast to something else (but I don't know what), which will result in a different type. The `fromValue` is templated (although it can be deduced), so the type is obtained and stored in the QVariant.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(QSharedPointer<GMResource>)` to be abe to wrap `QSharedPointer<GMResource>` type in `QVariant`